# Como comparar o conteúdo de dois vetores?

Tags: java, array

```
public class VetorTurma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int pontuacao = 0,nota,c;
        String nome;  

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            double gabaritoVetor[] = new double[10];
            double notaVetor[] = new double[10]; 

            System.out.println("Digite o gabarito: ");
            for(c=0;c < gabaritoVetor.length;c++){
                System.out.print("Gabarito | questão["+c+"]: ");
            gabaritoVetor[c]=sc.nextDouble();


            }
            int i = 0;
            for(i=0;i < notaVetor.length;i++){
                System.out.print("Questão["+i+"]: ");
                notaVetor[i] = sc.nextDouble();



            }

            if(gabaritoVetor==notaVetor){
                 pontuacao ++;


            }

            System.out.println("Pontuação: "+pontuacao);
     }
    }
```

O contador do if retorna sempre zero. O que deve estar errado?

OBS: Pode parecer estranho números como gabarito o certo seria a,b,c,d.Mas primeiro quero fazer com números e depois como caracteres.

Comment: Você quer comparar os valores de ambos os vetores? Do jeito que você está fazendo, o if compara se a referência aos dois objetos de vetor é a mesma, o que é falso. Você precisa fazer um for para rodar em cima do primeiro vetor e outro for interno pra comparar os todos os indices do segundo na medida que o primeiro for vai iterando os indices do primeiro vetor.

Comment: Sim, no caso vetorA[0]: 2 | vetorB[0]: 2.  if(vetorA==vetorB) c++. Essa é a ideia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que com esse ajuste, a sua pontuação possa ser calculada de forma eficaz.

Segue a solução:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VetorTurma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int pontuacao = 0, nota;
        String nome;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int gabaritoVetor[] = new int[3];
        int notaVetor[] = new int[3];

        System.out.println("Digite o gabarito: ");
        for (int c = 0; c < gabaritoVetor.length; c++) {
            System.out.print("Gabarito | questão[" + c + "]: ");
            gabaritoVetor[c] = sc.nextInt();

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < notaVetor.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Questão[" + i + "]: ");
            notaVetor[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (notaVetor[i] == gabaritoVetor[i])
                pontuacao++;
        }

        System.out.println("Pontuação: " + pontuacao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a diferença entre ter e não ter os colchetes?

Comment: Como se trata de um array, os colchetes são os delimitadores do mesmo. Desta forma, quando se chama o `notaVetor[i]` se faz referência para o conteúdo daquela posição do array.

Answer (score 9):

Ao fazer  `if(gabaritoVetor==notaVetor)`, você está comparando apenas a referência de ambos os vetores em memória, e como são objetos alocados em espaços diferentes, a comparação vai resultar em `false`e não vai incrementar. Veja o exemplo:

```
double vetor1[] = new double[3]; 
double vetor2[] = new double[3];

        System.out.print(vetor1 + " - " + vetor2);
```

Que retorna algo assim no [ideone](http://ideone.com/m03uCU):

> [D@106d69c - [D@52e922

Para comparar os valores, você pode iterar entre os índices dos dois vetores usando laço de repetição(como foi mostrado na resposta do @WeslleyTavares), ou usando a classe [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
 if(Arrays.equals(vetor1,vetor2)){
            System.out.println("vetor1  e vetor2 iguais");
        }else{
            System.out.print("vetor1  e vetor2 diferentes");
        }
```

Veja um teste completo de comparação usando `Arrays` entre vetores(iguais e diferentes) aqui no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YYUq33)**

> Obs.: perceba que o método [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(double[],%20double[])) compara os vetores par a par, e
>   eles serão iguais se as suas referencias em memória forem nulas, ou se
>   tiverem o mesmo tamanho, e tiverem os mesmos valores para os mesmo par
>   de índices.